# Google Apps Transition - Multiple MX Records?

Tags: backup, g-suite, mx-record

I'm testing out Google Apps for Business for my company, and I'd like to send mail both to the Google Apps MX servers as well as my existing server. This way I can test the functionality of Google Apps without disrupting my existing users and systems.

Is it as simple as adding the Google Apps MX records as additional MX records with higher cost (lower priority) than my existing MX records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  No matter how you setup the MX records, each email will only be delivered once (to the highest priority server that is available at the time of delivery.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any ideas on how to accomplish the goal?

Comment: You could setup aliases for each person, one for local delivery, one for user@googleappsmx.example.com.  Then have MX records for googleappsmx.example.com point to Google Apps MX records.